# How to create multiple instance of same provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using a provider to fetch the data and notify the listeners as follows:

```
class CategoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  Future<void> getData() async {
     ......
     ......
     notifyListeners();
   }

}
```

My `CategoryListView` widget is listening to this provider as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var collectionData = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
}
```

I'm pushing new instance of `CategoryListView` as follows:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CategoryListView.routeName);
```

I'm pushing new instances of `CategoryListView` from `CategoryListView` widget itself.
It works fine on pushing new instances, but on navigating back, all the `CategoryListView` widgets are showing the data of the latest `CategoryListView` widget pushed into the stack as it's listening to the same provider.
How can I create new instance of provider and associate it to a widget instance? Is there a better approach to handle this?

Comment: Ever solve this?

Comment: @Lee , I found a solution and posted as an answer. Please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it and I'm posting the solution so that it may help someone.

The new instance of provider is declared in `CategoryListView` class follows:

```
  final CategoryProvider collectionData = CategoryProvider();
```

Similarly, instead of passing associated data for `CategoryListView` as navigator arguments, I passed it as constructor values so that those values will be accessible in `initState()` function.

Hence pushing of a new instance of `CategoryListView` is changed from

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CategoryListView.routeName);
```

to

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
CategoryPage(constructorValue) ));
```

On `initState()` function, set the necessary values to the provider and make the necessary function calls.

```
 collectionData.catalogueId = widget.catalogueId;
 collectionData.loadNextPage();
```

On  `Widget build(BuildContext context)`, listening to the provider is changed from

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var collectionData = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
}
```

to

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff04063E),
        title: Text(widget.catalogueName != null ? widget.catalogueName : ""),
        
      ),
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: collectionData,
        child: Consumer<CategoryProvider>(builder: (_, ctl, __) {
          return _buildUI(collectionData);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Where `_buildUI(collectionData)` is a function which builds the UI from the provide instance `collectionData`.

Also, dispose the provider instance on dispose:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    collectionData.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```